# How Password stored in database in encrypted format?

Tags: java

how to store password in database in encrypted format????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not encrypt; hash. And better hash with [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). In Java you can use Apache [DigestUtil](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) to hash. Better hash using [SHA256](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha256Hex%28java.lang.String%29) algorithm.

Then when user passes his password, you hash the password match against hashed password. If the two hashes match, you got the correct password.

Comment: actually i hv created login page in jsp. and connected it with database..as i enter from login password in database shows what i put it on jsp.....i want to encrypt that field(i.e i must not able to see what some one write password)......so how to achieve it??

Comment: @Smith do you want that field in JSP to be printed as asterisks or dots? In that case that's a UI issue. use `<input type="password"></input>` to hide the characters. see this http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms06.htm

Answer (score 5):

Don't store them encrypted, store them hashed (unless you have a very, very, **very** good reason why you really need them in cleartext!). Use [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) as hashing algorithm.

Comment: You should also have a look at MessageDigest class. There are a few hashing algorithm you can use with it in java.

Answer (score 4):

simply encrypt password before storing to database 
 see
http://www.jasypt.org/

Comment: i have stored password in database in Encrypted format..now i want to compare with original password which user will put while login..So,to compare with stored hashed password

Comment: @smith: did u checked link?  see menhod `passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(inputPassword, encryptedPassword`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Hash-Value (MD5/SHA1) of the Password in your Database and compare it eachtime with the calculated Hash of the Usersinput. You will not be able to retriev the password but to rests it to a generated one which the user have to change on his next Login.

And here you have a very good [article](http://www.jonlee.ca/how-to-store-user-passwords-in-a-database/).